# Парсинг XML, никак не могу найти, в чем косяк

Tags: python-3.x, xml, парсер, xmlparser, lxml

Мне нужно распарсить документ XML на Python 3.x c помощью функции, которая принимает на вход название файла XML и  названия тегов, которые нужно оставить на месте, не трогая их (то есть все содержимое переданных в качестве параметров тегов нужно оставить без изменений), функция возвращает распарсенную строку.

В целом функцию я написала, но проблема в том, что она почему-то вытаскивает текст со всех тегов, игнорируя перечисленные в качестве параметров теги.

Помогите, пожалуйста, написать правильно функцию, где тут косяк? Уже очень долго ищу, никак не могу найти.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import json
import re

def specific_tags_not_parse(self, name_file, *args):
    f = open(name_file, 'r', encoding="UTF-8")
    string = f.read()

    tags_list = []
    for i in args:
        tags_list.append(i)
    tree = ET.parse(name_file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    my_list = []

    se_t = []  # множество для всех открывающихся и закрывающихся одновременно тегов
    element = re.findall('<.*?[/]>', string)
    for x in element:
        se_t.append(x)

    for it in root.iter():
        for it_tag in tags_list:
            if it.tag != it_tag:
                my_list.append(it.text)
            else:
                for a in se_t:
                    if a.find(it.tag) != -1:
                        my_list.append('<{} {}/>'.format(it.tag, dict_to_str(it.attrib)))

                    else:
                        my_list.append('<{} {}>'.format(it.tag, dict_to_str(it.attrib)))
                        my_list.append(it.text)
                        my_list.append('</{} {}>'.format(it.tag, dict_to_str(it.attrib)))
    my_list_2 = []
    for e in my_list:
        if e != None:
            my_list_2.append(e)
    return ' '.join(my_list_2)
```

Вот например файл xml с содержимым :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<div>
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998,897/Math/MathML" display="inline">
  <semantics>
    <mrow>
      <mrow>
        <mfrac>
          <mn>6</mn>
          <mrow>
            <mn>3.17</mn>
          </mrow>
        </mfrac>
        <mo>&#xB7;</mo>
        <mfrac>
          <mrow>
            <mn>11.2</mn>
          </mrow>
          <mrow>
            <mn>25</mn>
          </mrow>
        </mfrac>
        <mo>&#xB7;</mo>
        <mfrac>
          <mrow>
            <mn>17</mn>
          </mrow>
          <mn>6</mn>
        </mfrac>
        <mo>.</mo>
      </mrow>
    </mrow>
    <annotation-xml encoding="MathML-Content">
      <mrow>
    <mfrac>
      <mn>6</mn>
        <mrow>
          <mn>17</mn>
        </mrow>
    </mfrac>
      <mo>·</mo>
        <mfrac>
          <mrow>
        <mn>11</mn>
          </mrow>
        <mrow>
          <mn>25,564,98.9898</mn>
        </mrow>
        </mfrac>
          <mo>·</mo>
        <mfrac>
          <mrow>
            <mn>17</mn>
              </mrow>
            <mn>6.98798</mn>
            </mfrac>
          <mo>.</mo>
        </mrow>
    </annotation-xml>
  </semantics>
</math>
<csymbol cd="nums1">pi</csymbol>
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <mrow>
    <msqrt>
        <mrow>
        <mi>a</mi>
        </mrow>
    </msqrt>
    <mo>&#xB7;</mo>
    <mroot>
        <mrow>
        <mi>b</mi>
        </mrow>
        <mrow>
        <mn>3</mn>
        </mrow>
    </mroot>
    </mrow>
</math>
</div>
```

А я, например, в main делаю вот так
a = XLML()
print(a.specific_tags_not_parse('note2.xml', 'semantics'))

Должно получиться

```
    <semantics>
        <mrow>
          <mrow>
            <mfrac>
              <mn>6</mn>
              <mrow>
                <mn>3.17</mn>
              </mrow>
            </mfrac>
            <mo>&#xB7;</mo>
            <mfrac>
              <mrow>
                <mn>11.2</mn>
              </mrow>
              <mrow>
                <mn>25</mn>
              </mrow>
            </mfrac>
            <mo>&#xB7;</mo>
            <mfrac>
              <mrow>
                <mn>17</mn>
              </mrow>
              <mn>6</mn>
            </mfrac>
            <mo>.</mo>
          </mrow>
        </mrow>
        <annotation-xml encoding="MathML-Content">
          <mrow>
        <mfrac>
          <mn>6</mn>
            <mrow>
              <mn>17</mn>
            </mrow>
        </mfrac>
          <mo>·</mo>
            <mfrac>
              <mrow>
            <mn>11</mn>
              </mrow>
            <mrow>
              <mn>25,564,98.9898</mn>
            </mrow>
            </mfrac>
              <mo>·</mo>
            <mfrac>
              <mrow>
                <mn>17</mn>
                  </mrow>
                <mn>6.98798</mn>
                </mfrac>
              <mo>.</mo>
            </mrow>
        </annotation-xml>
      </semantics>
pi
a
&#xB7;
b
3
```

(отступы тут произвольные взяла, главное что текст со всех остальных тегов мы вытаскиваем)
то есть весь текст для всех тегов, кроме  semantics мы вынули, а тег semantics оставили полностью нетронутым с его содержимым. Важно, что на вход может быть подано несколько тегов, содержимое которых надо оставить без изменений

Comment: приведите пожалуйста пример XML файла и пример того, что вы хотите получить на выходе...

Comment: Добавила пример файла в условие

Comment: А то, что в "должно получиться" находятся и xml, и plaintext так должно быть? Выглядит странно, обычно нужно одно -- или нужный тег вытащить, или вытащить текст из указанного тега/тегов

Comment: на выходе должна получиться строка, то есть просто return ans_str(что-то вроде этого)